# Limit 1000 Records from CosmosDB Query

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I need to limit the results of a query to CosmosDB to 1000 records, I am trying to set the feed iterator to exit once the result list hits 1000 but right now it is stopping after 100 records. Here is my current code:

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<AS2InboundLogRecord>> RetrieveInboundLogs(string partitionKeyName, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            var inboundLogs = new List<AS2InboundLogRecord>();
            string continuationToken = null;
            int itemLimit = 1000;

            QueryRequestOptions requestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions()
            {
                MaxItemCount = 100
            };


            using (FeedIterator<AS2InboundLogRecord> setIterator = dbContainer.GetItemLinqQueryable<AS2InboundLogRecord>(true, continuationToken, requestOptions)
                    .Where(x => (x.PartitionKey == partitionKeyName || partitionKeyName == null) &&
                      (x.MessageDate >= startDate) &&
                      (x.MessageDate <= endDate))
                    .ToFeedIterator())
            {
                while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    FeedResponse<AS2InboundLogRecord> response = await setIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                    inboundLogs.AddRange(response);

                    if (response.Count >= itemLimit) { break; }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(inboundLogs.Count());
                return inboundLogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.MessageDate);
            };
        }
```

Any input would be appricated, thanks

Comment: Because you set `MaxItemCount` to `100` and it just fecth 100 records

Comment: Did I mis something. In your options it says `MaxItemCount = 100`. Sounds like that is your problem?

Comment: I thought MaxItemCount only set the size of a page to 100? So the iterator would return a page of 100 records until it hits 1000? I may be misunderstanding the documentation

Comment: @JonaldMonday Yeah you're right the `MaxItemCount` used for pagination, see the summary of `prop`  [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/RequestOptions/QueryRequestOptions.cs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to correct two things:

First: you set `limitCount` to `100` sound like it just fetch only 100 records , if this limit fetch count set it to `1000` otherwise goto `Second` phrase.

Second: your `if` condition may not work because you compare `response.Count` while `inboundLogs.Count` should be compare.

Correction:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AS2InboundLogRecord>> RetrieveInboundLogs(string partitionKeyName, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var inboundLogs = new List<AS2InboundLogRecord>();
    string continuationToken = null;
    int itemLimit = 1000;

    QueryRequestOptions requestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions()
    {
        MaxItemCount = 10000
    };


    using (FeedIterator<AS2InboundLogRecord> setIterator = dbContainer.GetItemLinqQueryable<AS2InboundLogRecord>(true, continuationToken, requestOptions)
            .Where(x => (x.PartitionKey == partitionKeyName || partitionKeyName == null) &&
                (x.MessageDate >= startDate) &&
                (x.MessageDate <= endDate))
            .ToFeedIterator())
    {
        while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            FeedResponse<AS2InboundLogRecord> response = await setIterator.ReadNextAsync();
            inboundLogs.AddRange(response);

            if (inboundLogs.Count >= itemLimit) { break; }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(inboundLogs.Count());
        return inboundLogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.MessageDate);
    };
}
```

As `cosmosdb` doesn't support `Skip` and `Take` you can also use `offset` and `limit` described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-offset-limit)
or you can also use `ContinuationToken` of `response` to make sure there is still item, something like:

```
do
{ 
    response = await setIterator.ReadNextAsync();
    //List<dynamic> documents = response.Resource.ToList();
    continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
    inboundLogs.AddRange(response);
} while (continuationToken != null && inboundLogs.Count <= itemLimit);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and info! I used your suggestion with the continuation token. Is there any impact on performance or RU consumption between either of your suggestions?

Comment: You are welcome, No I don't think so, but if performance is important for you, it is better to Metric different requests and choose best one, take a look at [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor-normalized-request-units)